ECS Fargate Issues
I have a fargate task with 8vCPU and 16gb memory. This fargate task currently runs a dockerfile on ECR which is about 7gb. It runs successfully. However, when I do a performance test on JMeter, the fargate task does not scale pass 10 threads. I assume the reason for this is because after a particular number of threads, the cpu utilization gets very high(about 87%) and then it begins to fail health check. Currently my ECS is behind a load balancer and I configured service autoscaling. However, as the traffic increases, the CPU utilization goes from about 30% to 80% in about 10 seconds, leaving the ECS tasks unhealthy before the autoscaling starts which takes about 2-3 mins.
What is the best way to scale this workload and make it handle a lot of concurrent requests.


What is the best way to scale this workload and make it handle a lot of concurrent requests.

Place your ECS service behind a load balancer, and configure application auto-scaling which will spin up more instances of your ECS task as needed.

I have done this. Currently my ECS is behind a load balancer and I configured service autoscaling. However, as the traffic increases, the CPU utilization goes from about 30% to 80% in about 10 seconds, leaving the ECS tasks unhealthy before the autoscaling starts which takes about 2-3 mins.

That would have been very good information to include in your question.

It sounds like your application simply can't handle scaling that fast, so you either need to slow down your performance tests, or if you think your application is actually going to get that much traffic, that quickly, you need to have more than one task always running, or use larger CPU Fargate instances or both.

@Techtacles how many concurrent users are you running in jmeter and what's the ramp up looks like?

The health check fails when it reaches about 20 concurrent users in jmeter and then it starts throwing errors.

@Techtacles you need to slow down your tests and design a variable load which correlates to the actual use case.
